# openstack cinder error on liberty

Tags: openstack, openstack-cinder

I have an install of Liberty RDO openstack. However, when i attempt:

```
[root@controller ~(keystonerc_admin:admin)]# cinder --insecure quota-defaults edc8225a13404a00b44d8099e060c3d5
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:769: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
  InsecureRequestWarning)
ERROR: The server has either erred or is incapable of performing the requested operation. (HTTP 500) (Request-ID: req-aee74e5b-b9da-460a-a4b1-14f67c165e48)
```

In Horizon, this error manifests itself as:

```
Error: Unable to retrieve volume limit information.
```

When navigating to horizon -> admin -> defaults.

The cinder logs show:

```
2016-03-10 02:07:19.970 30161 WARNING keystoneclient.auth.identity.generic.base [req-89efb8d4-299b-4cf6-bca3-386f6c4e9348 9bf9e8f990624c2ca0c08c1bf02edbdb edc8225a13404a00b44d8099e060c3d5 - - -] Discovering versions from the identity service failed when creating the password plugin. Attempting to determine version from URL.
2016-03-10 02:07:19.970 30161 ERROR cinder.api.middleware.fault [req-89efb8d4-299b-4cf6-bca3-386f6c4e9348 9bf9e8f990624c2ca0c08c1bf02edbdb edc8225a13404a00b44d8099e060c3d5 - - -] Caught error: Could not determine a suitable URL for the plugin
2016-03-10 02:07:19.971 30161 INFO cinder.api.middleware.fault [req-89efb8d4-299b-4cf6-bca3-386f6c4e9348 9bf9e8f990624c2ca0c08c1bf02edbdb edc8225a13404a00b44d8099e060c3d5 - - -] http://192.168.33.11:8776/v2/edc8225a13404a00b44d8099e060c3d5/os-quota-sets/edc8225a13404a00b44d8099e060c3d5/defaults returned with HTTP 500
2016-03-10 02:07:19.972 30161 INFO eventlet.wsgi.server [req-89efb8d4-299b-4cf6-bca3-386f6c4e9348 9bf9e8f990624c2ca0c08c1bf02edbdb edc8225a13404a00b44d8099e060c3d5 - - -] 192.168.33.11 - - [10/Mar/2016 02:07:19] "GET /v2/edc8225a13404a00b44d8099e060c3d5/os-quota-sets/edc8225a13404a00b44d8099e060c3d5/defaults HTTP/1.1" 500 425 0.082927
```

My cinder config:

```
[root@controller ~(keystonerc_admin:admin)]# cat /etc/cinder/cinder.conf | grep -vE '(^$|^\#)'
[DEFAULT]
my_ip=192.168.33.11
auth_strategy=keystone
debug=True
verbose=True
rpc_backend=rabbit
glance_host=192.168.33.11
enabled_backends=lvm
[BRCD_FABRIC_EXAMPLE]
[CISCO_FABRIC_EXAMPLE]
[cors]
[cors.subdomain]
[database]
connection=mysql://cinder:change_me@192.168.33.11/cinder
[fc-zone-manager]
[keymgr]
encryption_auth_url=http://localhost:5000/v3
[keystone_authtoken]
insecure=True
auth_uri=https://192.168.33.11:5000
auth_url=https://192.168.33.11:35357
auth_plugin=password
project_domain_id=default
user_domain_id=default
project_name=service
username=cinder
password=change_me
[matchmaker_redis]
[matchmaker_ring]
[oslo_concurrency]
lock_path=/var/lib/cinder/tmp
[oslo_messaging_amqp]
[oslo_messaging_qpid]
[oslo_messaging_rabbit]
rabbit_host=192.168.33.11
rabbit_userid=openstack
rabbit_password=change_me
[oslo_middleware]
[oslo_policy]
[oslo_reports]
[profiler]
[lvm]
volume_driver=cinder.volume.drivers.lvm.LVMVolumeDriver
volume_group=cinder-volumes
iscsi_protocol=iscsi
iscsi_helper=lioadm
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it could be this bug:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1272572

I don't know what way rdo deploys openstack - but it looks like you are using the v3 Identity API

```
encryption_auth_url=http://localhost:5000/v3
[keystone_authtoken]
insecure=True
auth_uri=https://192.168.33.11:5000
auth_url=https://192.168.33.11:35357
```

These unversioned auth endpoints present a http 300 'multiple choices' so they can work with cinder-pythonclient (v2.0) and openstack common client (v3).

I would determine - what is your default keystone endpoint (no version in endpoint = 3, otherwise /v2.0).

What version of keystone is Horizon using 'USE_IDENTITIY_API = X' in local_settings.py

the newer openstack common client uses a different systax for quotas - if you are on identity api v3

```
os quota set
    # Compute settings
    [--cores <num-cores>]
    [--fixed-ips <num-fixed-ips>]
    [--floating-ips <num-floating-ips>]
    [--injected-file-size <injected-file-bytes>]
    [--injected-files <num-injected-files>]
    [--instances <num-instances>] 
    [--key-pairs <num-key-pairs>]
    [--properties <num-properties>]
    [--ram <ram-mb>] 

    # Volume settings
    [--gigabytes <new-gigabytes>]
    [--snapshots <new-snapshots>]
    [--volumes <new-volumes>]

    <project>
```

Comment: thanks @Rob-d; in fact shortly after i posted i determined the same. Cinder was defaulting to keystone v3; when i only had v2 configured. Changing the `auth_uri=https://192.168.33.11:5000/v2.0` fixed it a little (but now i get a different error).